# java class identify about classloader

Tags: java, classloader

I have doubt with **Class**'s identify，**Class**'s identify should be `The same classloader instance` + `The same class full path`。But I make some test cases，it doesn't work。

I have a self-defined **ClassLoader**:

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileSystemClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private String rootDir;

    public FileSystemClassLoader(String rootDir) {
        this.rootDir = rootDir;
    }

    protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        byte[] classData = getClassData(name);
        if (classData == null) {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException();
        } else {
            return defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
        }
    }

    private byte[] getClassData(String className) {
        String path = classNameToPath(className);
        try {
            InputStream ins = new FileInputStream(path);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bufferSize = 4096;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            int bytesNumRead = 0;
            while ((bytesNumRead = ins.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesNumRead);
            }
            return baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String classNameToPath(String className) {
        return rootDir + File.separatorChar
                + className.replace('.', File.separatorChar) + ".class";
    }
}
```

The `Sample` class:

```
public class Sample {

    private Sample instance; 

    public void setSample(Object instance) { 
        this.instance = (Sample) instance; 
    } 
}
```

And a **test case**:

```
String classDataRootPath = "/Users/haolin/Github/jvm/target/classes";
FileSystemClassLoader fscl1 = new    FileSystemClassLoader(classDataRootPath);
FileSystemClassLoader fscl2 = new FileSystemClassLoader(classDataRootPath);
String className = "me.hao0.jvm.classloader.Sample";
try {
    Class<?> class1 = fscl1.loadClass(className);
    Object obj1 = class1.newInstance();
    Class<?> class2 = fscl2.loadClass(className);
    Object obj2 = class2.newInstance();
    Method setSampleMethod = class1.getMethod("setSample", Object.class);
    setSampleMethod.invoke(obj1, obj2);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It should occur `ClassCastException` when `setSampleMethod.invoke(obj1, obj2)`，because **obj1** and **obj2** are different **Class** (their **ClassLoader** is different)，but the code works well, doesn't throw `ClassCastException`。

Could someone suggest it?

Comment: They are in turn the same Class though correct? I don't see a difference between the two.

Comment: Yes, even **obj1** and **obj2** are the same full path class `Sample`，but the classloader loaded their class `Sample` are different，`obj1` is `fscl1`，`obj2` is `fscl2`，so `jvm` should regard their class is different，but didn't.

Comment: what is `class1 == class2` in your test?

Comment: Is the directory named by `classDataRootPath` on your classpath?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I think we are thinking of the same thing here ;P  I kinda suspect the class is loaded by the system classloader instead of that 2 `FileSystemClassLoader`s

Comment: Yes，I print their classloader `obj1.getClass().getClassLoader()` and `obj2.getClass().getClassLoader()`，both are `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@60dbf04d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be correct except for one important detail.  Classloaders exist in a hierarchy, and every `ClassLoader` delegates to its parent before attempting to load a class itself.  So if a common ancestor of your classloaders finds the requested class, then your classloaders will both return the same instance of that class.  Consider this example:

```
public class Foo {
    public void isFoo(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("object is a Foo: " + (obj instanceof Foo));
        Foo foo = (Foo) obj;
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File path = new File(".");
        URL[] urls = new URL[] { path.toURI().toURL() };
        URLClassLoader cl1 = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        URLClassLoader cl2 = new URLClassLoader(urls);

        Class c1 = cl1.loadClass("Foo");
        Class c2 = cl2.loadClass("Foo");
        System.out.println("same class instance: " + (c1 == c2));

        Object o1 = c1.newInstance();
        Object o2 = c2.newInstance();

        Method m = c1.getDeclaredMethod("isFoo", Object.class);
        m.invoke(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
same class instance: true
object is a Foo: true
```

This occurs because the current directory is part of the default classpath, so the parent classloader finds and loads `Foo`, and both custom classloaders return the instance from their parent.

Now, make this change to the test class and recompile:

```
File path = new File("foo");
```

Create the `foo/` directory and move `Foo.class` there.  Now the output is:

```
same class instance: false
object is a Foo: false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at Test.main(Test.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Foo cannot be cast to Foo
    at Foo.isFoo(Foo.java:4)
    ... 5 more
```

This is what you expected.  The system classloader can no longer find `Foo`, so the custom classloaders load separate instances of it.  The JVM sees the two `Class` instances as different classes even though they're identical, and the cast fails.

Comment: Thank you for answer，it's my negligence，I forget to delete the classpath's class file.